# In an Access form, how to return to previous record after requery

Tags: ms-access, vba

This should be an easy one.  This form is filtered by [Dismissed] = "N".  When the user clicks the "Dismiss" button, the [Dismissed] field changes to "Y".  After the requery, the form  should then return to the same row where the user was previously at.

```
Private Sub DismissButton_Click()
   Me!Dismissed = "Y"
   MsgBox "Dismissed!", vbOKOnly
   Dim GoBackToThisRecord As Integer
   GobacktothisRecord = Me.CurrentRecord
   Me.Requery
   Set Me.CurrentRecord=GoBackToThisRecord
End Sub
```

However, even though the built-in help files say that CurrentRecord is a read/write property, I get an "Invalid use of property" error message on this last line.

After setting the [Dismiss]="Y", and requerying the form, how do I get the user back to his/her previous location in the form?

Comment: I don't understand how this can work if the form is filtered to a value that the edited record no longer matches. I would never do it this way, as the number of records could change with a requery and the position in the recordset could change. You really should use the PK instead.

Comment: While this isn't likely going to be a problem I'd recommend Dimming GoBackToThisRecord as a long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand how your solution can work if the form is filtered to a value that the edited record no longer matches -- if you're filtered on [Dismissed] = "N" then changing the current record's Dismissed field to Y should cause the requeried form to exclude the record you've just updated.

That aside, I would never do it the way you've done it, as Me.CurrentRecord returns a number representing the position in the record. Since a requery can cause the number of records to change (e.g., somebody else edits or adds or deletes a record causing it to be included/excluded from the form's recordset) and the position of the sought-for record to change, I would use the PK instead.

```
  Dim lngPK as Long

  lngPK = Me!MyPKID
  Me.Requery
  With Me.RecordsetClone
    .FindFirst "[MyPKID]=" & lngPK
    If Not .NoMatch Then
       If Me.Dirty Then
          Me.Dirty = False
       End If
       Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
    End If
  End With
```

That won't deal with the filter issue, but I leave that aside, since it didn't seem to be the issue that I thought it would be from the description of the original problem.

Comment: My goal is just to keep the user in the same part of the recordset that they were before they requeried (which as you know, takes you back to the first record).  Since the Dismiss command would obviously remove that particular record from the view, the user would ideally end up at the next record in the set.

Comment: Well, that's not what you described as your goal. In fact, if the recordset didn't change otherwise, you'd end up at the record *after* the one that's no longer displayed. If I wanted to do what you're suggesting, I would still use the same approach, i.e., I'd get the PK of the next (or previous) record, store that, requery, and then navigate back to it via the RecordsetClone. Keep in mind that your approach will cause problems if the record that is removed is the last one in the recordset, whereas using the PK it won't matter where in the recordset the sought-after record is displayed.

Comment: Well, it's been about 13 months since you suggested it, and I'm now working on a completely different database, but I understand the value of your suggestion now :)

Answer (score 2):

I use this function:

```
Public Sub RequeryFormAndKeepCurrentlySelectedRecord(f As Form)
Dim Position As Long
  Position = f.CurrentRecord
  f.Requery
  If Position > 1 Then
    f.Recordset.move Position - 1
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. Fixed it myself.  The last line is now:

```
Me.Recordset.Move GoBackToThisRecord
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way to move to the previous record, whether it is a new one or not, is

```
Me.Recordset.Move GoBackToThisRecord -1
```