# Refresh forms recordset source with custom SQL query keeping current selection after closing second form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 2 forms in MS Access. One is an overview form as an endless form, the other shows details of the single records.
The overview form gets its content by a custom SQL passthrough query on opening:

```vb
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT tbl_Parts.strPart, Title, Comment FROM [tbl_Parts] inner JOIN [tbl_PartModules] ON tbl_Parts.strPart = tbl_PartModules.strPart ORDER BY tbl_Parts.strPart DESC"
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef, rst As DAO.Recordset
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
Dim strTmpConnQDF As String
strTmpConnQDF = CStr(Application.TempVars("tempvar_StrCnxn"))
qdf.Connect = strTmpConnQDF
qdf.sql = strSQL
qdf.ReturnsRecords = True

Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
Set Forms![frm_PartsOverview].Recordset = rst
Forms![frm_PartsOverview].Requery
'No rst.Close to have the data still in the Form!
Set qdf = Nothing
```

Within that overview, buttons can be used to change the underlying SQL query to show different records.

Each record has a "show details" button in the endless form which opens the detail form.

Within the detail form, I can change the data of the underlying record. After closing this form, I want to keep all settings (record selection, SQL query data) that were before opening the detail form. But I also want to update the underlying data, showing the changes made in the detail form also on the overview form.

I tried this code with the "hide" button of the detail form, but this does not work:

```vb
Forms!frm_PartsDetail.Visible = False
Forms!frm_PartsOverview.Recalc
Forms!frm_PartsOverview.Refresh
Forms!frm_PartsOverview.Requery
```

I tried all three variants (Recalc, Frequery, Refresh) but none of them did the trick.
I guess its because of the way I assign the SQL query as the recordsource of the form.
But how to update the recordsource, keeping all settings like they were before entering the detail form?

Comment: This should work. Try `Forms!frm_PartsOverview.Recordset.Requery`. Do not use Refresh method. It will reload all the records. Only use `Recordset.Requery`.

Comment: Does not work - error message "3251 operation not supported"

Comment: Did you use `Forms!frm_PartsOverview.Recordset.Requery`?

Comment: yes, I used exactly this

Comment: It seems that this is not possible with a passthrough-query according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67807594/me-recordset-requery-fails-with-error-3251-with-query-as-a-recordsource

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a me.Refresh  - that will (should) show updates to the form. (but, the fact of it being basedon a pt query probably will effect this. I suggest changing to a linked view - thus no pt query required and thus access can stay on the given row, and you can use a me.refresh. (with a PT query and you having assigned the forms data source "one time", then me.refresh is unlikely to work.

So, I suggest using a linked view for that form. (and performance will be just as good at the pt query - and your me.Refresh will work (to show any changes made to the table).

the other way? Grab the current row (PK) before you do the me.Requery. Then do a find first on the pk row, and jump back to the row in question.

So, ignoring you have a sub form etc.

Then this code:

```
 Dim PK       As Long
 PK = Me!ID
 
 Me.Requery
 Dim rst      As DAO.Recordset
 Set rst = Me.Recordset
 
 rst.FindFirst ("ID = " & PK)
```

However, as noted, if you base that form on a linked view, and not set the datasource as you do, then a me.Refresh will show any changes made, and also stay on that current row.

So, in your case, to re-calc, re-display, and show any updates, and return to current row you were on?

"air code warning"

```
  Dim PK      As Long
  Dim f       As Form
  Dim rst     As DAO.Recordset
  
  Set f = Forms!frm_PartsDetail
  PK = f!ID
  f.Requery
  Set rst = f.Recordset
  rst.FindFirst ("ID = " & PK)
```