# How to keep focus after requery in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using the following code in VBA to keep focus on a certain recordset even after requery :

```
With Forms!frmMain!frmMainSub
        strControlName = .Form.ActiveControl.Name
        lngCurrentPos = .Form.Recordset.AbsolutePosition
        .Requery
        .Form.Recordset.AbsolutePosition = lngCurrentPos
        .Form.Controls(strControlName).SetFocus
    End With
```

The problem with this code is that the subform is in datasheet view and is usually sorted by a field. Since the code above records the absolute position on dynaset- or snapshot-type Recordset object, it cannot keep track of the sorted datasheet.

Is there a better way to keep focus on a specific field after the form is requeired?

Edit:

This question is not a duplicate because there are answers about keeping the focus from the same form. The problem is that I am in a different form and also I want to preserve focus even when filter is applied to one of the fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In an Access form, how to return to previous record after requery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426371/in-an-access-form-how-to-return-to-previous-record-after-requery)

Comment: Have you actually tried using the techniques in the answer on the duplicate (using `.FindFirst` to navigate back to the record)? What went wrong? I'm unconvinced it's not a duplicate just by you stating you want to use it in different scenario's.

Comment: The `.FindFirst` one uses `me.` object which I cannot use cause I am in a differnt form. Doing something like `Forms!frmMain!frmMainSub.Form.RecordSource.RecordsetClone` does not work and gives me Object required error

Comment: Well, that's just because `RecordSource` should not be in there. It's just `Forms!frmMain!frmMainSub.Form.RecordsetClone`